# please suggest how to use vertx Timeout handler for vertx 3.7.1

Tags: vert.x, vertxoptions

i am trying this

```
router.put(/api).handler(TimeoutHandler.create(100,404)); router.put(/api).blockingHandler(this::handlebusinesslogic); 
handlebusinesslogic{
Thread.sleep(1000);
reponse.setstatuscode(200);
reponse.end();}
```

still, I see 200 ok response instead of 404 response. is there something missing from the code. is there an alternative way to do this.

is there a way to set a general timeout for all HTTP requests?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you shouldn't use `Thread.sleep()` while testing anything in Vert.x
In your case, this will also block the timeout handler, preventing the timeout.

Here's how you should test it:

```java
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        Router router = Router.router(vertx);

        router.route().handler(TimeoutHandler.create(100, 404));
        router.route().handler(event -> {
            // Instead of blocking the thread, set a long timer 
            // that simulates your long ASYNCHRONOUS request
            vertx.setTimer(1000, (l) -> {
                event.response().end("OK!");
            });
        });
        
        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router).listen(8080);
```

This example will return 404 as expected.

Comment: Hi Alexey, Thanks for your response. Is the Timeout for the thread or for just the ASYNC operations done by the thread.

Comment: The timeout is for the request. You shouldn't work with threads directly, if you use Vert.x, since Vert.x multiplexes them.

Comment: In my code, there is some business logic after sending OK response. I need to put timeout on that. please suggest how to do that

Comment: @ Alexey, does setMaxWorkerExecuteTime() help me here in anyway?

Comment: If your business logic is wrapped within non-blocking handlers, you should be fine. `setMaxWorkerExecuteTime` won't help you with that, though. AFAIK it only displays warning if worker is running for too long.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [this](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.vertx/vertx-core/3.9.8/io/vertx/core/http/HttpClientOptions.html).

1. setConnectTimeout(int connectTimeout)
2. setHttp2KeepAliveTimeout(int keepAliveTimeout)
3. setIdleTimeout(int idleTimeout)

Try changing values for these. #1 should work for your requirement.